# Why does Kuriyama always say "How unpleasant!"?

Tags: beyond-the-boundary

Kuriyama often says the phrase "How unpleasant!" (不愉快です！, Fuyukai Desu!)

[image: "How unpleasant!"]

Did they explain this in the light novel, or is this just a typical catch phrase to make her cute?

Comment: It's more of a catchphrase, like Shana's "shut up" (x3) line.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There isn't any deep meaning to Kuriyama's *fuyukai desu* / "How unpleasant!" in the light novel. It's just a thing she says frequently - a catchphrase.